# How to proceed if nullpointerexception received from getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-actionbar

I have below class in my android project:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        setupViewPager(viewPager);

        TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
    }

    ...
}
```

When inspecting code android says:

```
Method invocation 'getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)' at line 27 may produce 'java.lang.NullPointerException'
```

In theory, this situation does not have to happen but I would like to know what will be the best thing to do in case if it happened...

Maybe, using a try-catch block and show a polite error message to the user and finally exit application?

EDIT:
Below xml for my main activity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:tabMode="fixed"
            app:tabGravity="fill"/>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"  />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: please post your xml code for this activity.

Answer (score 1):

It is just a warning. It says there is a possiblity that the return value of `getSupportActionBar()` is null.

So, if you want to avoid this warning, null check before invoking `setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled` method on it.

```
ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
if (actionBar != null) {
    // method invoked only when the actionBar is not null.
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason why you get the warning is because the method is annotated with a flag `@Nullable` which indicates that the result might be `null`.

Based on the `setSupportActionBar`'s [documentation](https://developer.android.com/intl/zh-cn/reference/android/support/v7/app/AppCompatActivity.html#setSupportActionBar(android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar)):

> When set to a non-null value the getActionBar() method will return an ActionBar object

and common sense, you can expect it not to return a null object unless you failed to provide a valid view yourself (should be fixed right away) or if the whole android support library is failing (highly unlikely).

What I would do is throw an understandable exception if the error occurs:

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
if (getSupportActionBar() == null) {
  throw new IllegalStateException("Action bar not set! Toolbar view was: " + toolbar);
}

ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
```

Comment: ok, your solution seems ok, more or less as @hata, but is it correct to throw an exception to the user? user will see on the screen an exception that she/he does not know what is.... not helping her/him.